# Is it okay to mix different versions of Xilinx IP in a single design

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

Suppose the IP repository contains two versions of the same IP. Does Xilinx Vivado allow instantiating both versions in the same design, or can that conflict in some way?

Comment: I would think that if there were a resource problem you would find out in the fitting stage. I'd be worried that it would use the same version in both places because it may just instantiate module Block, instead of Block_1_9 and Block_1_5. You should be able to look through the code and check to a deep enough level to ensure that different blocks were used. Worst case, you could verify that the two blocks use different resources (although there can be some variability in this anyway)

Comment: Thanks. How can I check that the blocks use different resources?

Comment: I think when you go to compile, the fitter will throw up errors if the blocks use the same resources. If you have not bought the IP yet, you can try checking the Product Specs [example](https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/1-79drsh.html#productspecs). I'm not familiar enough with Vivado to know what resources are particularly sparse.